# How can i check whether the browser is active or not in crossrider?

Tags: browser-extension, crossrider

I need to calculate the browser using time in an extension. If i can check whether the browser is active or not, then it is easy to calculate the time. How is this possible in crossrider?

```
var focused = true;
window.onfocus = window.onblur = function(e) {
    focused = (e || event).type === "focus";
}
alert(focused);
```

i tried this code in background.js but it always display "true" even if i minimize the browser window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The focus and blur events are not available in the background scope of any extension, even ones not using Crossrider.

The common solution is to use the extension scope (*extension.js*) to detect the events and then pass the information to the background page using [messaging](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message).

Using your code as a base, the following example should help you achieve your goal:

**extension.js**

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  window.onfocus = window.onblur = function(e) {
    appAPI.message.toBackground({
      focus: (e || event).type === "focus"
    });
  }
});
```

**background.js**

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log('focus: '+msg.focus);
  });
});
```

[**Diclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]